# Access and munipulate the DOM using a for loop

Tags: javascript, dom

for a challenge, I am calling an the twitch TV API to get info and update my HTML.

Using a for loop, I succeeded to `setAttributes` for my `divs` and `appendChilds`. but when I want to update those childs, it is updating only the childs of the last `div`.

I need your help to update all my appended childs. Below is my code:

```
             // variables declarations to update the DOM
                var users = usersJson.data;
                var i;
                var usersIds = [];
                var channels = document.getElementById("all").children;
                console.log(channels);

                // pushing channels ids into an array for a later
                for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                    usersIds.push(users[i].id); 
                }

                var channelImg = document.createElement("img");
                var channelTitle = document.createElement("h3");

                for (var i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) {
                    channels[i].setAttribute("id", users[i].id);
                    channels[i].setAttribute("class", "channelInfo" + (i + 1) + " " + "channel" + (i + 1));

                    channels[i].appendChild(channelTitle);
                    channels[i].appendChild(channelImg).setAttribute("id", "img-holder" + (i + 1));

                    channelTitle.innerHTML = users[i].display_name;
                    channelImg.setAttribute("src", users[i].profile_image_url);

                }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpcz1r5k/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The creation of the elements needs to go in the for loop:

```
            for (var i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) {
                var channelImg = document.createElement("img");
                var channelTitle = document.createElement("h3");

                channels[i].setAttribute("id", users[i].id);
                channels[i].setAttribute("class", "channelInfo" + (i + 1) + " " + "channel" + (i + 1));

                channels[i].appendChild(channelTitle);
                channels[i].appendChild(channelImg).setAttribute("id", "img-holder" + (i + 1));

                channelTitle.innerHTML = users[i].display_name;
                channelImg.setAttribute("src", users[i].profile_image_url);

            }
```

When the creation is on the outside of the loop, appendChild only *moves* the element to the next parent. appendChild doesn't clone/duplicate the DOM elements. So you end up constantly updating the same DOM element and the last one ends up winning.